# Using getline() in separate function

Tags: c++, getline

I need to parse a .csv file, where delimiter between lines is '\n', but also any value can contain any number of '\n', if it is wrapped to " ".
So I wrote this function, which actually works when I put it to main, but does not change any variable when being separated from main.

```
void getWholeValue(ifstream &ip, string l) {
getline(ip, l, ',');
if (l[0] == '"') {
    string s;
    getline(ip, s, '"');
    l = (l + s);
}}
```

Here is an example of how I call the function:

```
struct Line {string customer;};
    int main(){
    Line *l = new Line;
    while (ip.good())
           {getWholeValue(ip, l->customer);
           }
    delete l;
}
```

So what exactly happens when I call getline like this? Is there any issues with pointers? Maybe there is any more accurate way to get what I want?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please, use a debugger and have a look at [std::getline()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). The extracted contents is returned via second parameter which is a `std::string&`. If you want that the result appears outside of `getWholeValue()` you could make `string l` a reference as well: `string &l`.

Comment: Btw. I don't see motivation of `Line *l = new Line;` and `delete l;`. If you change it to `Line l;` and remove the `delete l;` it will work as well. Due to the change, `l` would be stored on stack instead of on heap which I wouldn't count as disadvantage. (Of course, you have to change `l->customer` to `l.customer` in this case.)

Comment: Why not to make `getWholeValue` return string? It will make the API cleaner IMHO. `std::string getWholeValue(ifstream &ip)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for your function to correctly change the value of parameter l, you need the parameter to be a `std::string &` such that variable is passed by reference and therefore the original variable passed is changed instead of a temporary variable created inside the scope of the function. Simply change your `getWholeValue(ifstream &ip, string l)`

header to:
 `getWholeValue(ifstream &ip, string &l)`